# Understanding operator overloading & iterator why does it print out "wrhrwwr"?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, operator-overloading

In the following code the output is "wrhrwwr", I try to understand what the iterator is doing, also how the "++" is overloaded. It seems like it somehow skips the 'e'. However, the code is very unclear to me, maybe I can be helped.
Thank you

```cpp
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

class datas {
private: 
    const char *string,marker;
    const int len;
public:
    class hophop {
    private:
        const char *pos, next;
    public: 
        char operator *() { return *pos; }
        hophop operator ++() {++pos;while (*(pos+1)!=next)  ++pos; return *this; }
        bool operator !=(hophop &o) { return pos < o.pos; }
        hophop(const char *p, char m) : pos(p),next(m) {}
    };
    typedef hophop iterator;
    iterator begin() { return hophop (string, marker); }
    itrator end () { return hophop(string +len ,marker); }
    datas(const char *d,int l, char m) : string (d), len(l),marker(m){}
};

int main( void ) {

    datas chars ("we are where we were", 20, 'e');
    for (char c: chars)
        cout << c;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier to see by pulling `hophop` out of the `datas` class. Now you can see the `hophop` constructor and what it is up to. I would have removed the return value of the `++operator`, set it to void, to point out it does nothing here.

```
#include <iostream> 
class hophop {
private:
    const char* pos, next;
public:
    hophop(const char* p, char m) : pos(p), next(m) {}

    char operator *() { return *pos; }
    hophop operator ++() {
        ++pos;
        while (*(pos + 1) != next)
            ++pos;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator !=(const hophop& o) { return pos < o.pos; }
};

class datas {
private:
    using iterator = hophop;
    const char* string, marker;
    const int len;

public:
    datas(const char* d, int l, char m) : string(d), len(l), marker(m) {}

    iterator begin() { return hophop(string, marker); }
    iterator end() { return hophop(string + len, marker); }
};

int main(void) {

    datas chars("we are where we were", 20, 'e');
    //           w   r   h r  w  w r
    for (char c : chars)
        std::cout << c;

    std::cout << "\nusing a non range based for loop:"  << std::endl;

    for (hophop it = chars.begin(); it != chars.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it;

    std::cout << "\nor where the return value could be used:" << std::endl;
    auto it = chars.begin();
    std::cout << *it;
    for (; it != chars.end();)
        std::cout << *++it;
}
```

So now it may be easier to see how the hophop ++ operator is working. `operator *()` gets called at the beginning of the loop so no matter what the first character is, it gets retrieved. Then the `++operator` is called and it moves the iterator at least once forward and until it matches `next`. Then it returns the character before the match. Look at the comment in main. The first and every character before the `e` is returned.

If you have not used a debugger much, you should. by putting a break point in `operator++` you can see what is happening.

**UPDATE**

I had previously set the return value of the `++operator` to void. As @JaMiT points out, it is appropriate for the operator to return `*this`. I've also added two more loops, they should be clearer than using a range based loop. The third example actually uses the return value of the `++operator`, the first two loops don't.

And, get in the habit of not `using namespace std;` It will save you from troubles down the road.

Comment: Thanks!,that one really helped me a lot. So the ++operator didnt return anything usefull in my code?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, the `for` loop in main just calls the `++operator` to move the iterator. It does not look for, or do anything, with a return value.

Comment: [It is idiomatic for `operator++()` to return `*this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421719#4421719). Changing code to deviate from this convention is probably not a good idea when dealing with someone still learning the conventions. Especially when there is so little gained (a single line simpler) by doing so. *(I will grant that breaking that function over multiple lines is a good approach.)*